# Can app on GAE(google app engine) access Mysql server host on VPS/dedicated server?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

One of my small python web app hosts on GAE
but I prefer to change its database to Mysql.
GAE database is too special which rely on GAE and not good for future migration.
Can python app on GAE(google app engine) access Mysql server host on VPS/dedicated server?
(of course they are not in same local network with GAE)

if sure, what need to care(firewall, port policy and all others) for Mysql server being open to web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

- Open the single port needed (3306) inside your firewall of choice.
- Always install relevant security updates to the mysql server software as soon as possible.
- Create a new mysql user for access from your GAE instance.
- Possibly restrict access for this user to one single IP inside of mysql.
- (If this is true, you can also enforce it in your firewall of choice too, which hardens the access even more.)
- Grant this user as less rights as possible inside mysql.